# How to pass an input text value to build stage (Windows command prompt) in jenkins when there are multiple input texts (Jenkins-groovy script)

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to pass my input text boxes value to the build stage. I'm using the windows execute command prompt as the build setup. I have an **Active choice parameter** containing options as values and a **Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter** which includes a **groovy script** to be executed when the option is selected from the **Active choice Parameter.**

In **Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter** the groovy script contains an switch statement which will render multiple input text boxes as the output when an option is selected. I want to know how to get the values of each input text box separately maybe as an parameter to echo them out.
Such as in the build stage cmd,

***echo %{Input1 text box value}% %{Input 2 text box value}%***

Help me out! I have attached an image of the above case for your reference. Thank you :)

[Here is the image of the script, click on this to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdwVV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the guidelines of the [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) for generating the HTML, you can run something like this in the groovy script:

```
return """
<input name=\"value\" value=\"${ReactiveRefParam}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">
<input name=\"value\" value=\"${ReactiveRefParam1}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">
"""
```

Once the **name** attribute of the inputs is the same - **value**,
the Reactive Reference Parameter will hold the values of all inputs in the following format: `first_input_value, second_input_value ...`.
You can then just use the parameter value to extract each input value by splitting it by `,` or any other way.

here is an example for the [Active Choice Parameter config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vgV8.png).
The second one is exactly the same with different values

here is an example for the [Reactive Reference Parameter config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twzlm.png)

and here is the example for the [Build With Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSzbk.png) outcome page

Comment: This doesn't work out! It doesn't even gives the text boxes! Thank you Noam :)

Comment: @VimanthaPerera I added images for the configuration i used

Comment: Thanks Noam! But What I want is I want to get the input values when they are entered in the build stage and pass it to a python script as arguments in the execute batch command prompt or in the shell? Do you have any idea how to do that? Please help me out

Comment: In the example i gave if you run the build than the Reactive-reference parameter will contain the values from all inputs (separated by comma) and you can pass it directly to command line %Reactive-reference% and parse it with python or split it in the shell

Comment: Thanks Noam! It didn't exactly work the way I want. But I changed the way of giving the solution and this helped me.